# How to find array size by analysing assembler and C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I want to know how to find the value of the constant `M` from the following c and corresponding assembler code. Is there any method to determine `M` just by analysing the code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    
    int i=7;
    int a[14];
    
    a[i] = 99;
    
    int b[M];
    b[i] = 88;
 }
```

Assembly code given

```
main : 
endr64
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
subq $80, %rsp
movl $7, -80(%rbp)
movl -80(%rbp), %eax
cltq
movl $99, -64(%rbp,%rax,4)
movl -80(%rbp),%eax
cltq
movl $88, -76(%rbp,%rax,4)
movl $0,%eax
leave
ret
```

[image]

Comment: What did you try, and where are you stuck?  This reads like a "please do my homework for me".  Hopefully that is not your intention so please make the question more specific.

Comment: i tried converting c code to assembly using gcc with taking int M;  using command    gcc -S prorgam.c  but I dont know what is the value of M as nothing is mentioned about M in output (assembly code). i know value can not be 0. spend hour. Also nothing mentioned about M in given Assembly code too. i dont know much about assembly. Question :     int b[M];  what should be the value of M here. looking at assembly code

Comment: Does the assignment tells you that this code has undefined behaviour because M is so small?  That's surprising, you'd expect an assignment to use a valid C program, so it would make you doubt the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Think what is the format of the stack due to the allocation for the variables.
You can see that `i` is located on -80 from the stack pointer `rbp`. Also you can see that the `a[0]` is located at -64 (see `movl $99, -64(%rbp,%rax,4)`), and `b[0]` is located on -76 (see `movl $99, -76(%rbp,%rax,4)`). So, the start of b is located -12 bytes from the start of a, meaning, the length of b is 12 bytes.

Next you need to know is that the size of `int` is 4, so 12/4 = 3, therefore `M` was 3.

Use `gcc -S` on the following code and you can verify.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define M 3
int main(){

    int i=7;
    int a[14];

    a[i] = 99;

    int b[M];
    b[i] = 88;
 }
```

Comment: It's actually `-S` to show asm output.  And we only get the exact asm with `gcc -fstack-protector -mno-red-zone -fcf-protection=branch`.  https://godbolt.org/z/xs7z6MvWv. 
 Without stack-protector, it puts `i` at a higher address, above the arrays.  Without `-mno-red-zone`, it doesn't sub/leave to reserve stack space (but uses the same offsets relative to RBP).  Without `-fcf...`, no endbr64.

Comment: None of those are on by default on Godbolt, but some distros config GCC with and cf-protection `-fstack-protector-strong` (which would make a stack cookie in this function using even fixed-size stack arrays, which is good since it writes outside b[]!)  -fcf-protection=branch for endbr64 was new in GCC8, so we know this asm wasn't from an earlier GCC.  And it does look like GCC, based on use of `leave` (and also `mov $0, %eax` instead of xor-zeroing in a debug build.)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this picture of stack layout might help:

```
               --------------------
               | return from main |
               --------------------
               |  pushed RBP      |
               --------------------
RBP-08|RBP-04  |         |        |
               --------------------
RBP-16|RBP-12  |  a[12]  |  a[13] |
               --------------------
RBP-24|RBP-20  |  a[10]  |  a[11] |
               --------------------
RBP-32|RBP-28  |  a[8]   |  a[9]  |
               --------------------
RBP-40|RBP-36  |  a[6]   |  a[7]  |
               --------------------
RBP-48|RBP-44  |  a[4]   |  a[5]  |
               --------------------
RBP-56|RBP-52  |  a[2]   |  a[3]  |
               --------------------
RBP-64|RBP-60  |  a[0]   |  a[1]  |
               --------------------
RBP-72|RBP-68  |  b[1]   |  b[2]  |
               --------------------
RBP-80|RBP-76  |   i=7   |  b[0]  |
               --------------------
```

**a[7]** is addressed as **RBP-36** and **b[7]** would be addressed as **RBP-48** (if only array b[] would have been allocated this big).